# Add menudrawer (external library) to Android Studio 0.5.2

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, drawer

I decided to download android studio because of pretty good look and popularity. First problem i met is adding external library. Most tutorials are for older versions. Things i did:

- Created 'libraries' directory and put [THIS](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer/tree/master/menudrawer) library inside
  [image]
- Inside settings.gradle added

> ```
> include ':app:libraries:drawer'
> ```

- Inside src in build.gradle added

> ```
> compile project(':app:libraries:drawer')
> ```

under

> ```
> dependencies
> ```

After pressing "sync project wih gradle files" i got:

```
Gradle 'SCR' project refresh failed:
         Cause: cannot get property 'compileSdkVersion' on extra properties extension as it does not exist
```

Pastebin sourcefiles:

settings.gradle inside project: http://pastebin.com/NvuPG1St

build.gradle inside project: http://pastebin.com/AT0Kjj8F

build.gradle inside src: http://pastebin.com/HjTKUazU

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Use this structure:

```
root
  app
     build.gradle
  libraries
     drawer
       build.gradle
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
```

Change your `settings.gradle` with

```
include ':app'
include ':libraries:drawer'
```

Change dependency in your app/build.gradle

```
compile project(':libraries:drawer')
```

In build.gradle inside the drawer you have to specify your sourceset inside the android block.

```
android {

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['aidl']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
}
```

**UPDATE** (after your images):

In your `drawer/build.gradle` you are using:

```
compileSdkVersion parent.ext.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion parent.ext.buildToolsVersion
```

You should define in your `root/build.gradle`

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 19 
    buildToolsVersion = "19.0.3"
}
```

and change the `drawer/build.gradle` in:

```
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
```

Comment: Did as you said, still same problem :( I made some screenshots: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/w7nmihvzbrvudud/Aci6HGXuAN#/

Comment: Didn't help, any other ideas? https://www.dropbox.com/sh/phrfsd2tkgtpccg/OKEdZRDg1j#/

Comment: Yes. You have to check your error message. Now it is different. You are using the same logic with minSdkVesion with parent.ext.minSdkVersion.Change it.

Comment: Like this? https://www.dropbox.com/s/xctx5ovtgo6mrp9/Zrzut%20ekranu%202014-03-27%2013.47.19.png Still same error like in problem #2

Comment: yes, but you have to define it in your gradle.build in the root folder or you can use gradle.properties.

Comment: I think I'm doing it wrong way. I have tried to add this fragment of code: http://pastebin.com/Tqqiy5ma and because of no effects i think I need to extend this fragment somehow: http://pastebin.com/GMcVu024 I'm sorry, these questions may be silly for you, but if we fix it out I'll write small guide for others.

Answer (score 0):

[Controlling Android properties of all your modules from the main project](http://androidcodegeeks.com/controlling-android-properties-of-all-your-modules-from-the-main-project/)

```
// SDK Version and Build Tools used by all subprojects
ext {
   compileSdkVersion = 21
   buildToolsVersion = '21.1.2'
}
```